# Java Scanner Throws InputMismatchException even when next token appears to fit data type

Tags: java, regex, io, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'm currently working with the Java Scanner class and I'm getting a very strange InputMismatchException. I initialize the scanner like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

in.useDelimiter("\n?.*:");
```

When I call `System.out.println(in.next());`, it prints `1500` to the command line, which is the correct value. However, if I call `System.out.println(in.nextInt());` the Scanner throws an InputMismatchException. I don't think I'm printing trailing newlines or whitespace, and I'm sort of lost as to why this is happening.

EDIT: Here's the data format for what I'm reading in:

`Data Description:100
Next Data Description:200`

EDIT: Calling `Integer.parseInt(in.next());` results in a  `NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"00`.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/bc7hyk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `InputMismatchException` isn't strange at all, because your regex isn't cross-platform compatible. You're likely a Windows user, so your text file will have `\r\n` as it's line endings, not just `\n`.

Thus the proper pattern would be:

```
in.useDelimiter("\r?\n?.*:");
```

To accept `\r\n` or a single `\n`.

You could also try to work with `System.lineSeparator()` to support different line endings, but then you would need to wrap that with parenthese so the regex quantifier `?` applies to both chars `\r\n` for Windows systems:

```
in.useDelimiter(String.format("(%s)?.*:", System.lineSeparator()));
```

The issue with that approach is that it fails when using Windows as the operating system, but receiving the file from somewhere else, which itself just uses `\n`. So I recommend the first approach.

Comment: One can use `\R` in a regex to match any Unicode line break sequence, so maybe `"\\R?.*:"` would be better.